# Silverstripe: Issue with session. Strange behaviour

Tags: silverstripe

I have the following in the init() function of my Page_Controller:

```
if ($this->ClassName != 'Trail' && $this->ClassName != 'Ride'){
    Session::clear('RelatedTrails');
} elseif ($this->ClassName == 'Ride') {
    Session::clear('RelatedTrails');
    Session::set('RelatedTrails', $this->getTrails());
}
```

Ride Class:

```
function getTrails() {

        return $this->Trails();
    }
static $many_many = array(
        'Trails' => 'Trail'
    );
```

Trail Class

```
    class Trail extends Page {

        .....
        static $belongs_many_many = array(
            'Rides' => 'Ride',
        );
....
}
```

This sets a session when the user hits a ride page. I need to make this session information available on the Trail page ONLY when they go directly from a ride page to a trail page.

It is giving me issues in that when I hit a 'Ride' class page, the session is not set. When I comment out the Session::clear from the first part of the if statement, the session is set correctly, however I need it to clear on any other page type.

I have tried putting an echo and a die in the first part to see if it is falling into here but it is never hit. This is very strange behaviour. Can anyone see what is going on here?

UPDATE:
To explain further: 
I have rides and trails. A ride can contain many trails. On the ride page, there is a menu which allows the user to click through to the trails which are associated with the ride. When they click through from the ride to the trail there is a menu which shows the other trails associated with the ride they just clicked through from. The trails for the menu are stored in the session which is set on the Ride page. I need to retain this session as they navigate the other trails via the menu so I can continue to show those related trails.

If the user links directly through to the trail page (not via a ride). I need to know this so that I can just show ALL trails as I do not have any associated trails.

Comment: I personally find session always a bad way to handle what I think you are trying to do.
if you could explain the relation between the Ride Page and the Trail Page, and maybe post the relevant code, I think we might find an even better way to handle it.

Comment: Thank you. I've added an update and some more code

Comment: what class is this code in?
And is Trail a page or a DataObject?

Comment: Trail is a page. My session setter is in the page class. GetTrails and the many_many are in the Ride class

Answer (score 2):

rather than saving all Trails into session I would just set the ID of the holder
on the Trail you can then get the Ride Page and fetch the trails

would this be working in your case?

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    ...
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        // clear on every page
        Session::clear('rideID');
    }
    ...
}

class Ride_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    ...
    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        // sets the session after clear
        Session::set('rideID', $this->data()->ID);
    }
    ...
}

class Trail_Controller extends Page_Controller {
    ...
    public function getRelatedTrails()
        // get the ID from session before clear
        $rideID = Session::get('rideID');
        parent::init();
        $ridePage = DataObject::get_by_id('Ride', (int)$rideID);
        if ($ridePage && $ridePage->Trails())
            return $ridePage->Trails();
        // here you could return some default Trails, in case no RideID is set
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The only issue I am having is that if I set the session to clear from anywhere (even the homepage) the session is not being even set on the ride page

Comment: because if someone navigates to the trail independently of a ride, I need to be able to display all the other trails not just those related to a ride. You see, a trail can belong to many rides so we wouldn't know which others to show so we'd show them all. I've managed to sort it by passing a querystring from the ride to the trail and only showing the related trails if this exists. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: For some reason, if I was clearing the session from anywhere (even a class unrelated to the current class) it was not allowing the session to be set. I manage to get around it by simply setting the session on the ride page as before and then passing a querystring to the trail page to identify that we'd come from from a ride page and then keep passing the querystring until we leave that section. That way, if someone came directly to the trail page they would be shown all trails, not just those that relate to a specific ride. Huge thanks for your time in this though!